# Reading length of on of the object in a Multiple objects Json Array using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

All I need is to select a region from the first drop down then it will fill the second dropdown with the data from the Json array accordingly.

I facing an issue with reading the length of the selected region array after selecting the region from the drop-down. I get undefined due to the length, but when I remove the .length property, I get the array correctly.

```js
const myJSON = '[' +
  '{"المنطقة الشرقية":[' +
  '{ "cityName":"الدمام","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الخبر","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"القطيف","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"صفوى","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"سيهات","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"عنك","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الظهران","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الجبيل","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الهفوف","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"رأس تنورة","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"بقيق","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"المبرز","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"رحيمة","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الأحساء","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الخفجي","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"النعيرية","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"تاروت","deliveryTime":"1" }' +

  ']},' +
  '{"المنطقة الوسطى":[' +
  '{ "cityName":"الرياض","deliveryTime":"" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الخرج","deliveryTime":"" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"بريدة","deliveryTime":"" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"عنيزة","deliveryTime":"" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الرس","deliveryTime":"" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"المجمعة","deliveryTime":"" }' +

  ']}' +
  ']';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
var regions = document.getElementById("m_continent");
// Optional: Clear all existing options first:
regions.innerHTML = " <option value='-1'>اختر منطقة التوصيل</option>";
// Populate list with options:
var j = 0;
var allCities;
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key) {
  var value = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObj[key]);
  regions.innerHTML += "<option value=\"" + j++ + "\">" + value + "</option>";
});

function fillCities(val) {
  var cities = document.getElementById("m_cities");
  var region = regions.value;
  cities.innerHTML = " <option value='0'>اختر مدينة التوصيل</option>";
  var allCities = myObj[region];
  console.log(allCities.length);

  for (var i = 0; i < allCities.length; i++) {
    var city = allCities[i];
    console.log(city);
    cities.innerHTML += "<option value=\"" + city + "\">" + city + "</option>";
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="direction:rtl">

  <h2>مدن وأوقات التوصيل</h2>
  <p>يمكنك تقدير وقت وصول طلبك لمدينتك</p>
  <label for="m_continent">اختر منطقتك</label>
  <select id="m_continent" onchange="fillCities(this.value)">
  </select>
  <br>
  <label for="m_cities">اختر مدينتك</label>
  <select id="m_cities">
    <option value="0">اختر المنطقة أولا</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <p id="delivery-time"></p>


</body>

</html>
```

All I want is to find the length of the selected array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `myObj[region]` will not output the `cities` but the `region` itself, you need to get the `cities` inside, I work around it by `Object.values(myObj[region]).flat()` to get the cites.

```js
const myJSON = '[' +
  '{"المنطقة الشرقية":[' +
  '{ "cityName":"الدمام","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الخبر","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"القطيف","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"صفوى","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"سيهات","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"عنك","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الظهران","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الجبيل","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الهفوف","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"رأس تنورة","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"بقيق","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"المبرز","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"رحيمة","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الأحساء","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الخفجي","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"النعيرية","deliveryTime":"1" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"تاروت","deliveryTime":"1" }' +

  ']},' +
  '{"المنطقة الوسطى":[' +
  '{ "cityName":"الرياض","deliveryTime":"" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الخرج","deliveryTime":"" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"بريدة","deliveryTime":"" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"عنيزة","deliveryTime":"" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"الرس","deliveryTime":"" },' +
  '{ "cityName":"المجمعة","deliveryTime":"" }' +

  ']}' +
  ']';
const myObj = JSON.parse(myJSON);
var regions = document.getElementById("m_continent");
// Optional: Clear all existing options first:
regions.innerHTML = " <option value='-1'>اختر منطقة التوصيل</option>";
// Populate list with options:
var j = 0;
var allCities;
Object.keys(myObj).forEach(function(key) {
  var value = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(myObj[key]);
  regions.innerHTML += "<option value=\"" + j++ + "\">" + value + "</option>";
});

function fillCities(val) {
  var cities = document.getElementById("m_cities");
  var region = regions.value;
  cities.innerHTML = " <option value='0'>اختر مدينة التوصيل</option>";
  var allCities = Object.values(myObj[region]).flat();

  for (var i = 0; i < allCities.length; i++) {
    var city = allCities[i];
    console.log(city);
    cities.innerHTML += "<option value=\"" + city.cityName + "\">" + city.cityName + "</option>";
  }

}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body style="direction:rtl">

  <h2>مدن وأوقات التوصيل</h2>
  <p>يمكنك تقدير وقت وصول طلبك لمدينتك</p>
  <label for="m_continent">اختر منطقتك</label>
  <select id="m_continent" onchange="fillCities(this.value)">
  </select>
  <br>
  <label for="m_cities">اختر مدينتك</label>
  <select id="m_cities">
    <option value="0">اختر المنطقة أولا</option>
  </select>
  </div>
  <p id="delivery-time"></p>


</body>

</html>
```